# MySql SELECT, sum one column based on another column

Tags: mysql, select, sum

Here is my table

```
sku   |  type   |  qty
abc      order      3
abc      refund     1
abc      order      5
def      order      2
def      refund     1
```

I want to get the qty of the sku where type is "order" and deduct where type is "refund.

So expected qty for sku 'abc' would be **7** and for 'def' would be **1**.

The query I have doesn't do it as desired.

```
select sku, type, sum(qty) 
from table 
group by sku 
having type ='order'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
  sku, 
  type, 
  sum(CASE WHEN type = "order" THEN qty ELSE -qty END)  AS sum
FROM table
GROUP BY sku